# Prove the limit of the following complex sequence equals $ 1 $ or $ -1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z_{n+1}=0.5 \cdot (z_n + \frac{1}{z_n} ) $ for all natural $n$. Assume that $z_0$ is non-zero complex numer. Show, that limit of such sequence equals $ 1$ if $z_0$ Has positive real part and $-1$ if its real part is negative. I'm not even sure if it is true, Banach contraction principle doesn't apply in this particular case... I'm literally clueless.

Comment: Multiply $z$, subtract $z_{n+1}$ both sides and skip $n,n+1$ : $(z^2 - 2z + 1)/2=0$. Now maybe you can come up with something.

Comment: wait, that's not right, i must have slipped. momentary slip of $z$sons. dammit, manic phase, disconnect. cya.

Comment: if you drop the $n$s which are rude anyway and rewrite it becomes $z^2-1=0$ which you can factor.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$z_{n+1}=\frac 12 \left(z_n + \frac{1}{z_n} \right)\implies z_{n+1}=z_n-\frac{z_n^2-1}{2z_n} $$ This is the iterative scheme for the solution of $z^2-1=0$ using Newton method.